# i18n internationalization Changing terminology

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I want to change the terminology of my Angular app.

Basically i18n is what I need however I dont care about changing the local or even get the localization and switching language. The language will be english the only thing that is going to change is some text within my app.

For example, I have two terminology (T1 and T2) and whether I select one of those two I want different static text to change.

T1 : Create an object

T2 : Create an object (some other text)

Do you know how to do it? My main issue is the complexity of the i18n module since it s made for a total change of language.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at angular i18n, angular has support for internationalization

Comment: I tried but my main issue is that there arent any example of what I want.
Basically I need a simple text translator and I use i18n to do it easier but I dont know how to convert english from english. And I dont need any localization neither

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated Angular 6 to Angular 7 and I used Ngx-translate instead. As I thought I18n was too complex and not really useful in my case.